# Descargar archivo con file_get_contents

Tags: php, laravel, archivo

Resulta que estoy intentando descargar un archivo

de esta manera

```html
 $options = array('http' => array(
     'method'  => 'GET',
     'header' => 'Authorization: Bearer '.$access_token
 ));

 $context  = stream_context_create($options);

 $file = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Al momento que se descarga ese archivo, Necesito guardarlo en mi Servidor Local

pero, He intentado acceder a los atributos pero no sirve

Teniendo en cuenta que cuando hablo de archivo pues es un archivo (Imagen, Documento, Jpg. Zip. Etc)

Entonces como puedo acceder a esos atributos cuando he descargado ese archivo?

Answer (score 0):

Pff lo resolvi mejor con Guzzle

```
    $client = new Client();
    $file =  $client->request('GET',$url,[
        'headers' => [
            'Authorization'     => 'Bearer '.$access_token,
        ]
    ]);
```

Comment: Creo que te falta algo de contextualización, por mientras revisa [Como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)